# Multiple Build-Tasks with changing sets of dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to run tests of an library against different backend implementations.
The implementations are injected in my project by the magic of Spring.

Currently I do this, by changing the line

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mycorp.exmpl' name: 'redis-backend' version: '0.0.1'
```

to

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mycorp.exmpl' name: 'mongo-backend' version: '0.0.1'
```

to

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mycorp.exmpl' name: '<whatever-backend>' version: '<whatever.version>'
```

then running

```
gradlew test
```

(resp. clicking on 'test' in my IntelliJ IDE)

---

This is cumbersome. And I can't do that with my build pipeline (I guess).

In my imagination, I would be able to create

- a task `testRedis` which depends on the task `buildRedisTestClasses`
- a task `testMongo` which depends on the task `buildMongoTestClasses`
- ...

so I can just select the correct task in my IDE or run all of them in my build pipeline.
I found some hints on the web, that you can use something like this:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.mycorp.exmpl', name: 'redis-backend', version: '0.0.1', configuration: 'redis'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mycorp.exmpl', name: 'mongo-backend', version: '0.0.1', configuration: 'mongo'
}
```

But thats about where I stopped finding/understanding.
(As you might notice, I am a gradle novice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something alike:

```
./gradlew test -Dbackend=redis

dependencies {
    if (System.getProperty("backend") == "redis") {
        implementation "org.mycorp.exmpl:redis-backend:0.0.1"
    } else {
        implementation "org.mycorp.exmpl:mongo-backend:0.0.1"
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
./gradlew test -Dbackend=redis-backend:0.0.1

implementation "org.mycorp.exmpl:${System.getProperty("backend")}"
```

Making it a project property `-Pbackend` with a default value suggested.

See [Environment Options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#environment_options).